# NSToolbarItem Subclass not calling events

Tags: objective-c, events, nstoolbaritem

I've created a subclass for `NSToolbarItem` and am trying to catch the `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` in order to change its state (that's what I added in my subclass as `NSToolbarItem` doesn't support states out of the box).

Problem is that the event `mouseDown:` is never called, even though I set my toolbar items' class identities in Interface Builder to the one of my new class.

Why is this? NSToolbarItem is related to `NSView`, so it should be capable of events no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSToolbarItem is a subclass of NSObject, not of NSResponder. The event is never called because it is never supposed to handle any. An NSToolbarItem is like a NSDictionary for an NSToolbar, it stores what it needs to draw.

Comment: So I can't get any events for them whatsoever?

Comment: @DavidSchiefer what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to give the toolbar items the ability to have states like NSControls do. Assigning them states works, but changing it upon click does not due to the problem above. :(

Comment: @DavidSchiefer they can be selected though, might want to look into that